# How do I test that an accessible embedded hyperlink is clickable/not clickable when the screen reader is on/off?

Tags: javascript, react-native, asynchronous, jestjs, es6-promise

I have a function that detects whether the screen reader is enabled or not within a react native application. If it is enabled then an embedded hyperlink within a Text component will be "clickable" with the use of a screen reader. This works correctly when testing using Android Emulator. My problem is that I cannot write a test case to verify this behaviour.

```
export const ClickablePasssage: React.FC = () => (
  <>
    <Text
      accessibilityRole="link"
      accessibilityLabel="This is a link. Click here to go to the browser"
      onPress={() => onClickHyperlink('url')}
    >
      <Text >
        This is a link.
      </Text>
      <Text onPress={() => Linking.openURL('url')}>
        Click here
      </Text>
      <Text >
        to go to the browser
      </Text>
    </Text>
  </>
)
```

```
export const onClickHyperlink = async (url: string): Promise<any> => AccessibilityInfo.isScreenReaderEnabled().then((enabled) => { enabled && Linking.openURL('url') })
```

This is the test case I wrote. I can test that either unit test will run successfully, but when both tests are present, it will just hang forever (unit test case ran for 30 mins and did not complete). What am I doing wrong?

```
describe('onClickHyperlink', () => {
  afterEach(() => {
    jest.resetAllMocks()
  })
  it('calls a url when the screen reader is on', async () => {
    jest.spyOn(AccessibilityInfo, 'isScreenReaderEnabled').mockImplementation(() => Promise.resolve(true))
    jest.spyOn(Linking, 'openURL').mockImplementation(() => Promise.resolve(true))

    await onClickHyperlink('url')
    await expect(Linking.openURL).toHaveBeenCalledWith('url')
  })

  it('does not call a url when the screen reader is off', async () => {
    jest.spyOn(AccessibilityInfo, 'isScreenReaderEnabled').mockImplementation(() => Promise.resolve(false))
    jest.spyOn(Linking, 'openURL').mockImplementation(() => Promise.resolve(true))

    await onClickHyperlink('url')
    await expect(Linking.openURL).not.toBeCalled()
  })
})
```

Answer (score 0):

The answer was to resolve all Promises so that they run to completion, and clearAllMocks instead of resetAllMocks.

```
describe('onClickHyperlink', () => {
  afterEach(() => {
    jest.clearAllMocks()
  })
  it('calls a url when the screen reader is on', async () => {
    jest.spyOn(AccessibilityInfo, 'isScreenReaderEnabled').mockResolvedValue(true)
    jest.spyOn(Linking, 'openURL').mockResolvedValue(true)

    await onClickHyperlink('url')
    expect(Linking.openURL).toHaveBeenCalledWith('url')
  })

  it('does not call a url when the screen reader is off', async () => {
    jest.spyOn(AccessibilityInfo, 'isScreenReaderEnabled').mockResolvedValue(false)
    jest.spyOn(Linking, 'openURL').mockResolvedValue(true)

    await onClickHyperlink('url')
    expect(Linking.openURL).not.toBeCalled()
  })
})
```